# JS - Как удалить все элементы массива кроме последнего?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, подскажите, есть ли какой-нибудь способ, чтобы методом splice() удалить все элементы в массиве, оставляя только последний?

Comment: в чем проблема записать последний элемент в новы массив?

Comment: возьмите только последний

Comment: У меня специфичный массив с хранением callback функций. Просто хотелось бы сразу вычищать ненужные функции из массива. Конечно я могу просто брать последний, а потом, после завершения удалить весь массив. Но всё-же, стало интересно, можно ли очистить массив раньше.

Comment: перед выполением колбека использовать `.shift`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let test = [1,2,3,4];
test = [test.pop()];
console.log(test);
```